# Assigning one structure to another in C

Tags: c

Suppose i have 2 strutcures `s1` and `s2` containing array of 10000 elements each. If I copy one structure to another like `s1=s2` and by loop from 1 to 10000 and then `s1[i]=s2[i]`. Will there be any speed difference between the two methods? If yes, then please tell which one will be faster and why?

Comment: Do you like difficulties? If yes, then go with second method.

Comment: Don't forget element at index `0`!

Comment: @pmg: ... and forget the one at index `10000`!

Answer (score 2):

#### Executive Summary:

On my compiler, all of these are transformed into calls to `memcpy()` like functions. They happen to be different, but the compiler more or less recognizes that all of these implementations are functionally identical.

The performance difference between these various `memcpy()` implementations would likely be minimal.

#### Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct S {
    int x[10000];
};

void impl1(struct S *x, struct S *y) __attribute__((noinline));
void impl1(struct S *x, struct S *y) {
    *x = *y;
}

void impl2(struct S *x, struct S *y) __attribute__((noinline));
void impl2(struct S *x, struct S *y) {
    memcpy(x, y, sizeof(*x));
}

void impl3(struct S * restrict x, struct S * restrict y) __attribute__((noinline));
void impl3(struct S * restrict x, struct S * restrict y) {
    for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
        x->x[i] = y->x[i];
}

int main() {
    struct S x, y;
    impl1(&x, &y);
    impl2(&x, &y);
    impl3(&x, &y);
}
```

#### Resultant LLVM Code

```
define void @impl1(%struct.S* nocapture %x, %struct.S* nocapture readonly %y) #0 {
  %1 = bitcast %struct.S* %x to i8*
  %2 = bitcast %struct.S* %y to i8*
  tail call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %1, i8* %2, i64 40000, i32 4, i1 false), !tbaa.struct !1
  ret void
}

define void @impl2(%struct.S* %x, %struct.S* %y) #0 {
  %1 = bitcast %struct.S* %x to i8*
  %2 = bitcast %struct.S* %y to i8*
  %3 = tail call i64 @llvm.objectsize.i64.p0i8(i8* %1, i1 false)
  %4 = tail call i8* @__memcpy_chk(i8* %1, i8* %2, i64 40000, i64 %3) #1
  ret void
}

define void @impl3(%struct.S* noalias nocapture %x, %struct.S* noalias nocapture readonly %y) #0 {
  %x2 = bitcast %struct.S* %x to i8*
  %y3 = bitcast %struct.S* %y to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* %x2, i8* %y3, i64 40000, i32 4, i1 false)
  ret void
}
```

#### Compiler Information

```
[10:04am][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code that the compiler will generate for expression `s1 = s2` will be faster than using explicitly a user defined loop. Very likely the compiler will use stnadard C function `memcpy`

Comment: It might not exactly use the standard `memcpy` but perhaps some implementation specific variant like e.g. `__builtin_memcpy` in GCC (which in turn could be sometimes used for the standard `memcpy`)

Comment: ... which is probably done because it is legal to self-assign but illegal to self-copy with `memcpy`. Back in the day when assignment used `memcpy` some analysis tools made "false positive" complains about overlapping `memcpy`.